# Error in packages imported in OpenALPR using JNI method in Java on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, java-native-interface, ubuntu-16.04, openalpr

I want to build the sample code of openalpr library using jni method in java on Ubuntu 16.04.When I run this code in eclipse neon it shows error in packages imported as cross mark in code.

imported package is import com.openalpr.jni.Alpr;
Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error:Unresolved compilation problems. Alpr cannot be resolved to a type.
 Please anyone help me. It will be useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the required libraries in eclipse `Build Path` and try.

Comment: yes  when I copied my sample code in eclipse neon it added libraries by default. The added library is JRE system library. But when I try to add the referenced libraries it is not accepted. I don't know what to do please help me.

Comment: can you confirm if "openalpr.jni" jar has been added in build path ? if not added then please follow these steps to add, http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)

Comment: thanks. But i don't know from where can i get the jar files and copied into lib folder. There is only JRE system library and no other jar files present. Please help me.